# Angular2: Keep getting a 400 bad request error when posting to API but when using a RestClient I get a 200 Ok

Tags: rest, angular

I am busy with a small web app where I am trying to post to a API using a RestService but keep getting a 400 bad request.  When I do the exact same post using the Insomnia Rest client I get a 200 Ok...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong/what I can look at to find out what's going on?

Update:
It turns out the issue is a incorrect header, there's still a unresolved error i'm getting when trying to add the correct header...
Question continuation link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613330/angular2-very-vague-error-when-using-angular-http-requestoptions-where-angular)

**My error:**

> http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/StockTake/AddToStockTake Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
>       stockTake:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/StockTake/AddToStockTake. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
>       main.bundle.js:47711 failure: server error

**My code:**

stock-take.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';

import { StockTakeModel } from '../../models/stock-take.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'stock-take',
  templateUrl: './stock-take.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-take.component.css']
})
export class StockTakeComponent implements OnInit {
    stockTakeForm: FormGroup;
    stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService) { 
    this.stockTakeForm = fb.group({
        'SheetNo':['', Validators.required],
        'BinNo':['', Validators.required],
        'BarCode':['', Validators.required],
        'Quantity':['', Validators.required]
    });
    }

    doStockTake(val: any) {
        //console.log("val:" + JSON.stringify(val));
        //this.stockTakeModel = new StockTakeModel(0, 0, val[Object.keys(val)[2] '', val[Object.keys(val)[0]], val[Object.keys(val)[1]], val[Object.keys(val)[3]], 0);
        this.stockTakeModel = val;
    this.stockTakeModel.StockTakeID = '0';
    this.stockTakeModel.IDKey = '0';    
    this.stockTakeModel.ProductCode = '';
    this.stockTakeModel.PackSize = '0';
    console.log(this.stockTakeModel);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.stockTakeModel));
    this.submitStockTake(this.stockTakeModel);
    }

  submitStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) {
      //console.log(stockTakeModel);

    this.restService.postStockTake(stockTakeModel)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure: " + res);
    }
    );
    this.stockTakeForm.reset();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

submitStockTake function from rest.service.ts:

```
postStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) : Observable<Response> {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(stockTakeModel));

        return this.http.post(this.API_URL + "StockTake/AddToStockTake", JSON.stringify(stockTakeModel), this.headers)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }
```

Comment: Now looking at your previous question... you should anyway use `this.options` instead of `this.headers` in your post request. And your rest api is actually accepting POST request and not GET? Just checking ;)

Comment: No it's accepting get requests but not post.  I tried to use get with requestOptions before and had the same issue.  Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Well, you have to make sure your rest is accepting post, and not get. That would of course cause an error if rest is accepting get instead of post. And do change `this.headers` to `this.options` instead.

Comment: When you are sending a get request, rest needs to have get as well. And when you are sending post, rest has to have post as well. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It works fine when using the Insomnia Rest client...  So it can't be the API...  I had the exact same issue in the past when using RequestOptions with my working get requests.  This is the first Post request I have to do for this app and can't think of any way of getting around using RequestOptions anymore...

Comment: Could it possibly have anything to do with ng-cli/webpack?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue and resolved it by removing proxy. Please check if you have set any proxy.

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that you are not quite posting the same thing both ways - perhaps different request headers? Perhpas the browser running RestClient has authenticated? Inspect the actual requests in the network tab and check URL, headers, authentication etc - something has to be different.

Comment: Under the network tab I get the following error under the request:  The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected
message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation
of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:...  So i'm guessing that means there's something wrong with the JSON that gets sent?

Comment: Ths JSON that gets sent is:
{"SheetNo":"a11","BinNo":"b8","BarCode":222,"Quantity":2,"StockTakeID":"0","IDKey":"0","ProductCode":"","PackSize":"0"}
The only two things I see that might be an issue there is the empty string ProductCode?  And also the number values aren't surrounded by ""?  Not sure if that would be an issue...

Comment: So it seems it's being sent as content-type: text/plain...  Any idea how to correctly add the headers in an angular2 post request?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into things... here: [angular.io http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update)

it seems you aren't supposed to stringify (anymore), so try:

```
postStockTake(stockTakeModel: string) : Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      return this.http.post(this.API_URL + "StockTake/AddToStockTake", { stockTakeModel }, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }
```

Comment: take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613330/angular2-very-vague-error-when-using-angular-http-requestoptions-where-angular

Comment: I try to do that but it gives me a net::err connection reset in chrome console...  Code is in the post above.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand. Could you please add the link to your question, so that people do not get confused and react the same way I do ;) Thanks!

Comment: @user2094257 I undeleted my answer and updated, try the above and see what happens :)

Comment: i'm still getting the exact same error...  This very unusual...  I wonder what this could possibly be...  Maybe it could be angular-cli related...

Answer (score 0):

You should authorise the header "Authorization" on your server side